# unique id in imap php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, imap

I am using `imap_search` to get a list of Emails FROM `INBOX` and `SENT ITEMS`.

I have a grid that showing the Mail headers first ,when user clicks on one row i want to show entire content,like body,attachment etc ..

to achieve this there should be a UNIQUE ID for each messages.

how can i get UNIQUE ID for messages , i know about the `SE_UID` option will return the UNIQUE ID'S but UNIQUE ID are only in one Mail box ,

I can see same ID'S on INBOX and SENT ITEMS.

Please help me.

**Note : I am using Codeigniter with Peeker Library.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completely unique ID is made up of the mailbox name (eg `INBOX`), the `UIDVALIDITY` returned when a mailbox is selected, and the message `UID`.

You need to select the relevant mailbox and provide the correct UID to fetch the right message.  UIDs are *not* unique between different mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UID of an email to do operations on any email in any mailbox such as INBOX and SENT.

You can find more information http://phpmaster.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-1/ in this article